# how to reload component's html once a service's variable value changed

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm using a service named 'globalVariables' to share data between application modules & components, inside that service there is a variable called 'var'
and there are two components A,B that are consuming that service and 'var' variable.
How can I reload the html of component A once component B changed the value of specific variable belongs to service x.

here is the code of the A component:

```
    <div>
            <div>
                  <app-header> </app-header>
            </div>
            <app-side-nav-bar [input] = "globalVariables.selectedModule" > 
            </app-side-nav-bar>
   </div>
```

type script code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalVariablesService } from './shared/global_variables.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class A {
   constructor(public globalVariables: GlobalVariablesService) {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Observable**

You can use `observables` in your `GlobalVariablesService`, then other components subscribe to observables, and you call `next` when `var` is changed, then components will be notified and will be refreshed (depends on how to subscribe)

**@Output**

The other way is using `@Output` and event emitters to emit and event when values is changed, then components subscribe to that event and get notified when `var` is changed

**ng2-simple-global**

The other way is using ng2-simple-global [npm](https://github.com/J-Siu/ng2-simple-global) package, see the example in [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/J4GvVp/)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two options:

#### Use an Observable

The shared value is stored in an Observable. When the value changes, the Observable will emit this change and therewith notify all the subscribers.
So your service has a `getValue(): Observable<ValueType>` method, which a your component can subscribe to and a `setValue(value)` method, which calls `.next(value)` on the Observable, so that all subscribers will be notified.

Read more about this pattern in this [blog article](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/). (Hint: A more advanced approach in the same direction would be using Redux.)

#### Use `@Input` and `@Output`

Instead of using a service, a component emits an event via the `@Output` property when something has changed and the change is passed down the component tree via `@Input` properties.